# style attribute not defined when i check two passwords if match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple registration form and the password inputs are:

```
<label for="pass">Password:</label>
    <div class="input-group input-group-md">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></span>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" id="pass">
    </div>
    <br>
    <label for="pass_confirm">Confirm password:</label>
    <div class="input-group input-group-md">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" id="confirmPass">
    </div>
    <br>
    <p id="passwordMatch"></p>
```

I want the paragraph with id="passwordMatch" to show up and depending on the result to show the exact text needed. My jquery code is:

```
$('#confirmPass').on('keyup', function () {
        if ($('#confirmPass').val() == $('#pass').val()) {
            $('#passwordMatch')[0].style.display = "block";
       // use array to convert jquery to object     $('#passwordMatch').html('Password match!').css('color', 'green');
        } else {
            $('#passwordMatch').html('Password do not match!').css('color', 'red');
        }
    });
```

But when i type some random passwords in the inputs the console is telling me that the .style attribute is not defined. Before that i was using $('this') but i found out that i get an object and because of that i cant access DOM directly. Nevermind, changed it with if('#confirmPass').val() and i still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

If you *need* to access the DOM object directly you should use `$('#passwordMatch')[0].style.display = "block";`

But as you already use jQuery I suggest you to use `$('#passwordMatch').show();`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using .style on a jquery Selector - try this instead of .style:

```
$('#passwordMatch').css("display", "block");
```

Answer (score 0):

change the line of code to:

```
 $('#passwordMatch').css({'display':'block'});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#passwordMatch')` returns a collection, so it doesn't have a style attribute.  You should probably pick whether you are going to be using jQuery or pure javascript and stick to it.  jQuery -> `$('#passwordMatch').css('display','block');`

If you really wanted to, you could also do:

```
$('#confirmPass').on('keyup', function () {
        if ($('#confirmPass').val() == $('#pass').val()) {
            $('#passwordMatch')[0].style.display = "block";
            $('#passwordMatch').html('Password match!').css('color', 'green');
        } else {
            $('#passwordMatch').html('Password do not match!').css('color', 'red');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I dont think `$('#passwordMatch')` is an array or array like object

Comment: @user2181397 https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/ -- second paragraph `Calling jQuery() (or $()) with an id selector as its argument will return a jQuery object containing a collection of either zero or one DOM element.`  It's actually a collection which is array like.

Comment: Snippet from [here](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)
**Calling jQuery() (or $()) with an id selector as its argument will return a jQuery object containing a collection of either zero or one DOM element**
Internally it use `document.getElementById`. Array method are used on the collection after doing `Array.prototype.slice.call(collection)`

Comment: @user2181397 In your snippet, what are the first 6 words after "will return"?  **a jQuery object containing a collection**

Comment: @ Robert McKee will you like to tell me why this [**snippet**](https://jsfiddle.net/hxnekocd/) is throwing an error when I am trying to implement array method on it

Comment: @user2181397 Because you aren't using `$('#testId')`.  `$('#testId')` returns a collection, while `document.getElementById('testId')` returns a DOM object.

Comment: Check the same jquery link you shared. It is clearly mentioned internally it uses `document.getElementById`

Comment: Uses doesn't mean it's the only thing it does, nor does it mean that it returns exactly what getElementById returns. Here is your snippet that works with both jQuery and pure javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/hxnekocd/2.  Technically `$('#testId')` doesn't return an array, it returns a jQuery object that contains a collection, but array methods don't work on collections, so your snippet wouldn't have worked even if you used the jQuery method.  As such, I've updated my answer to say collection instead of array although it's a minor point.